# How to loop through the database to retrieve the review section

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to loop through the firebase to retrieve all the reviews submitted by each user and have also added their username so that I can match them because each review is unique to the user. I just have found it easier to append their username instead of using increment values as shown in my picture... I can get the array to display on the screen but when using the arrays to retrieve the info.getReview() method, I am getting null... I guess, the second array has two username piano and musician. Should only say musician correct? I am not sure if I am doing this correctly here but think I should use array to loop though...

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Medical Clinics"); // getReference() is the root
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                    int count = (int) snapshot.child("ID").getChildrenCount();



                    Information info = snapshot.getValue(Information.class);


                   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                       String Id = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("ID").getValue());

                       Id = Id.replace("{", "");
                       Id = Id.replace("}", "");
                       Id = Id.replaceAll("Id by", "");
                          String[] username = Id.split("=");
                //       Id = Id.substring(Id.indexOf("=") + 1);


                        Information info2 = snapshot.child("Reviews, Rating and Services by " + username[i]).getValue(Information.class);


                        //       for (int i =0; i < words.length; i++) {
                        assert info != null;
                   //     assert info2 != null;

                        String txt;

                     //   if (info2.getReview().isEmpty()) {
                    //        Toast.makeText(View_Review.this, "There are no Reviews provided yet for this particular Medical Clinic!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //        return;
                     //   } else {
                     //       txt = "Medical Clinic: " + info.getName() + "\n\nReviews: " + info2.getReview(); //+ "\n\nService 1: " + info2.getServices() + "\n\nService 2: " + info2.getServices2() + "\n\nService 3: " + info2.getServices3() + "\n\nService 4: " + info2.getServices4() + "\n\nService 5: " + info2.getServices5() + "\n\nService 6: " + info2.getServices6() + "\n\nService 7: " + info2.getServices7() + "\n\nService 8: " + info2.getServices8() + "\n\nRating: " + info2.getRating();
                            txt = "ID: " + username[i];

                             System.out.println(Id);
                         //    System.out.println(info2.getReview());

                            list.add(txt);
                        }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
              //  }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your structure can be simplified as below:

```
-RingWood Family Medical Center
 |
  -MJ0jfdsk2(unique id for user)
   |
    -rating
    -review
    -services3
    -username

  -MJ1kjksf2(unique id for user 2)
   |
    -rating
    -review
    -services3
    -username

    ...
```

By doing the above you can easily iterate over RingWood Family Medical Center's children and obtain, both the username and the review.

For more information on best practices for JSON structure you can read below from Firebase page.
Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Happy coding!

Comment: Do you mean that I should be using the push() method to assign for each user?

Comment: but how would I retrieve those unique id by using the getKey() method?